# Mysql query distinct desc order

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

Why can I not get Desc order for total_time_driven_at_this_trip?

```
    SELECT DISTINCT (`name`), 
           MAX( `total_time_driven_at_this_trip` ) as trip
     FROM `users` 
LEFT JOIN `trip_nsws` ON users.id = trip_nsws.user_id
 GROUP BY `user_id`
 ORDER BY `total_time_driven_at_this_trip` DESC
    LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Comment: Do *not* use `DISTINCT` in a `GROUP BY` -- utterly redundant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cause you aliased it as `trip` and are using `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT `name`, MAX(`total_time_driven_at_this_trip`) as trip
FROM `users` LEFT JOIN `trip_nsws` ON users.id = trip_nsws.user_id
GROUP BY `user_id`
ORDER BY `trip` DESC
LIMIT 0, 30
```

Comment: @OMG, I merely copied the OP's query. However, I don't see the *subquery*. Feel free to edit my answer or post your own.

Comment: Sorry, the OP's misuse of brackets threw off my reading comprehension. +1

Comment: @OMG, agreed. Cleaned it up a bit and incorporated your comment about `DISTINCT` as it seemed misused with the `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 2):

There is no column `total_time_driven_at_this_trip` in your result set to use for ordering.

There is only `DISTINCT(name)` and `trip`.

You probably want to `ORDER BY trip DESC`.